# iOS Firebase Snapshot.value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to print my data from firebase into Xcode. However, I can never print the snapshot.value into my label (named as "polar"). Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var polar: UILabel!
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("Total gallons:").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let ionic = snapshot.value as? String
        self.polar.text = ionic
```

Why isn't my self.polar.text working? It should print my data onto the label, but it never shows up. Please help, thanks.

Data in my firebase database

[image: Click here to see my data in my firebase database]

Comment: You’re reading a snapshot and treating its value as a string... it’s not a string. It’s a serial of child nodes, you could iterate over those child nodes to get their values but it’s unclear which one you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
ref.child("Total gallons").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let ionic = snapshot.value as? [String: Double] {
        self.polar.text = ionic
    }
})
```

You should notice that `"Total gallons"` doesn't have ":" at the end. And `ionic` is a dictionary [String: Double], not a text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your snapshot as **Dictionary** first.

You could do:

```
guard let ionic = snapshot.value as? [String: Double] else { return }
print(ionic) // This will print snapshot. 
//You still need to add logic here to parse values from dictionary.

DispatchQueue.main.async {
     // Update UI elements here
}
```

self.polar.text = ionic